# Can I access DB from django template?

Tags: database, django, templates

Suppose I have a model `Photo` with an `ImageField`.

I tried to iterate all photo objects in a template by `{% for photo in Photo.objects.all %}`.
Nothing comes up.

Is this impossible?

Comment: Please show your view's code. As Preet said, templates don't get direct access to models; they only get what's in the context plus anything middleware adds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way this is done is with a view that looks something like:

```
def photo_view(request):
    return render_to_response('app_name/photos.html', {
        'photos': Photo.objects.all()
        })
```

And then the template (in `app_name/templates/app_name/photos.html` in this example) has something like:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
```

---

If you really want to do `{% for photo in Photo.objects.all %}`, then your view code must pass `Photo` via the context:

```
def photo_view(request):
    return render_to_response('app_name/photos.html', {
        'Photo': Photo
        })
```

Bear in mind that this is not really any better of a way to do it, as template syntax is a lot more restrictive than Python. For example, there is no way to do `{% for photo in Photo.objects.filter(...) %}` in the template; the filtering needs to happen in the view.

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking about it the wrong way.

The HTTP request gets routed to a view.

The view does any business logic (which may involve accessing the DB via ORM), and then passes any required data/objects as a context dictionary to the templating system.

The templating system only sees what it has been passed from the view. If the object is a lazily-evaluated ORM DB iterator, then sure, it can access DB. But the view must pass that object into the template's context.

Try `{{Photo}}` in your template to make sure it is actually being passed an object named `"Photo"` by the corresponding view. You may need to inspect source of the generated html (in case due to its `repr` it does something weird with angle brackets and doesn't display properly in your browser.)